# Androidアプリのファイルサイズについて

Tags: android, build

Android開発初心者になります。

現在オフライン環境でのアプリをしているのですが、
プロジェクトファイルのサイズが10GB弱ありまして、
MBPの2013でのビルドに30分以上かかります。

そこでファイルサイズの大きく不要なファイルを退避させたいのですが、
どのファイルが不要なのか、調べることができませんでした。

サイズの大きいフォルダは、
app/buildが5GB
app/srcが1.6GB（動画1.4GB）
となっております。

動画ファイルは更に4倍になる予定なので、
どうしたものか途方に暮れています。

何かしら解決策をご教授いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 動画が1.4GB*4になる、とありますがどう考えてもアプリに含めるのにそれは大きすぎないですか？まずは外部リソースにしたりエンコードしなおすなどして縮小したりすべきかと思いますが…… メディアリソースを除いたコードだけでも200MBあるというのであれば、それも大きすぎる気がしますね……中身が何かは知らないのでなんとも言えませんが。

Answer (score 1):

> そこでファイルサイズの大きく不要なファイルを退避させたいのですが、
>   どのファイルが不要なのか、調べることができませんでした。

これは不要なファイルを探して削除したい。ということでよいのでしょうか。

AndroidStudioを利用しているのであれば、アプリ内で未使用のリソースを削除できます。
詳細は以下の記事を参照してください。
http://qiita.com/konifar/items/aa4bc60c78163c3ec354